# Meecrowave - setting relaxedQueryChars in Tomcat 9 embedded

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9

I'm unable handle requests with curly braces in query string parameter values.

I've tried to set `tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow` property but does not seems be supported anymore. In my case Meecrowave has Apache Tomcat 9.x embeded.

```
Meecrowave.Builder builder = new Meecrowave.Builder();
builder.setScanningPackageIncludes("my.packages");

try (Meecrowave meecrowave = new Meecrowave(builder)) {
    meecrowave.bake().await();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At last I've found this solution that seems to work well

```
final Meecrowave bake = meecrowave.bake();
bake.getTomcat().getConnector().setProperty("relaxedQueryChars", "|{}");
bake.await();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible - as any connector property - to pass it through configuration properties as "connector.attributes.relaxedQueryChars":

```
try (final Meecrowave meecrowave = new Meecrowave(new Meecrowave.Builder()
         .property("connector.attributes.relaxedQueryChars", "|{}"))
    .bake()) {
    // anything
}
```